# How to replace first line of a text file in Java?

Tags: java

Every time I implement the addVet method i need to replace the first line of the text file to include the number of objects.
Here is my addVet method:

```
public static void addVet(Veterinarian newadd){
    Veterinarian.Vet.add(newadd); 
    try{
        try (PrintWriter write = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("VetList.txt",true)))) {
            write.println();
            write.print(newadd.getPetName());
            write.println();
            write.print(newadd.getBirthday());
            write.println();
            write.print(newadd.getSpecies());
            write.println();
            write.print(newadd.getBill());
            write.println();
            write.print(newadd.getOwner());
        }
    }
    catch (IOException cnw){
        System.err.println("file cannot be written into");
    }
}
```

I Don't know what method to use to write the file over.
Here is the text file:

```
3
hopper
2003
kangaroo
555
Melody_harper
ketty
2009
cat
44
Kitty_katz
Spot
2005
Dog
333
Dottie_Marks
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: I don't think a text file is appropriate if you need to modify one item toward the beginning while leaving the rest intact.  What happens when the number goes from 9 to 10 or 99 to 100?  All the other characters in the file will have to shift over.  Basically you need to rewrite the whole file from scratch.  But I could be misunderstanding your problem.

Comment: If you just arranged your data in a normal way, you wouldn't _need_ the first number indicating the the number of "objects". By normal, I just bean in a tabular way, with rows and columns with some common delimiter. Then all you need is a while loop to read the data row by row

Answer (score 1):

The object is creating a new file if none exists, if it does then it will call it. In the write() method put what you want to writ in the txt file. The close() method just signifies the end of writing on the file.

```
FileOutputStream object=new FileOutputStream("file.txt",true);
object.write(byte[]);
object.close();
```

Comment: There is another way I to do this if you don't like this one.